# when to use String.prototype.localeCompare over Intl.Collator?

Tags: javascript

The performance improvement when using `Intl.Collator` is huge. The functionality between the two is identical. This brings the question, why use `String.prototype.localeCompare` at all, other than to use it conveniently like `str.localeCompare(str2)`?

Comment: I would prefer to use LocaleCompare if the performance does not impact your system a lot. Because the naming of LocaleCompare is more semantic.  The browser may improve the performance later, just wait for the browser to update the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare:

> In implementations with Intl.Collator API support, this method simply calls `Intl.Collator`.
> When comparing large numbers of strings, such as in sorting large arrays, it is better to create an `Intl.Collator` object and use the function provided by its `compare()` method.

There is another difference in that `localCompare` has better support with older browsers/runtime, but by now it's probably not as relevant. Practically `localCompare` will call `Intl.Collator` everywhere.